# hyperlink is not working in android UC browser

Tags: javascript, android, hyperlink, uc-browser

I am stuck with one problem. I am trying to open android app on hyperlink which is placed in my website.

Below is the link:

```
href="intent:#Intent;action=com.example.myapp;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;S.ret=http://192.168.1.10:777/result.aspx;S.msg_from_browser=Launched%20from%20Browser;end"
```

This above links works like a charm in another browser which I have tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and default android browser. But I am unable to open my app using UC Browser.

Any help / trick / suggestion / solution would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. UC Browser may do some url href optimizations/transformations. Could you test it by displaying href as text?
2. UC Browser may not process intent href at all. Ask UC Browser support for it.